# Let $(X,\mathcal{M}, \mu)$ be a finite measure space. If $(f_n)$ converges $\mu$-a.e. to $f$, then $f_n \rightarrow f$ in measure as well.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I was attempting this question but I'm not sure if my solution is right, especially because I don't think I'm using the finiteness of $\mu$ at any point. For sake of clarity, $(f_n)$ is a sequence of $\mathcal{M}$-measurable functions converging $\mu$-almost everywhere to $f$ (which is thus also $\mathcal{M}$-measurable). From this fact, we know that, for a given $\epsilon>0$, there exists $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that, if $n \geq N$, then $|f_n(x)-f(x)|< \epsilon$ holds $\mu$-almost everywhere. In particular, the set $$\{ x \in X : |f_n(x)-f(x)| \geq \epsilon\}$$ is $\mu$-null whenever $n \geq N$, so of course
$$\mu(\{ x \in X : |f_n(x)-f(x)| \geq \epsilon\}) \rightarrow 0$$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$, proving $f_n \rightarrow f$ in measure as well.

Would this argument suffice? It almost seems too easy to be right.

Comment: It's wrong because $N = N(x)$ depends on $x$.

Comment: It is easy to fix by applying Egoroff's theorem, which is of course, where you will need the finite measure assumption. Alternative approach is dominated convergence (which again needs finite measure assumption)